# VS Code Dynamic Import syntax error statement expected

Tags: ecmascript-6, visual-studio-code

Any idea how to get rid of this warning in VS Code

```
  const loadAnalytics = () => {
    import(
      /* webpackChunkName: "chunk-analytics" */ './analytics'
    ).then(page => page.init());
  };
```

[image]

"Declaration or Statement expected", the code actually compiles file just annoying to keep seeing this warning in VS code.

Comment: You can set `"javascript.validate.enable": false` in your .vscode/settings.json to disable vscode's javascript validation and use eslint extension instead: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=dbaeumer.vscode-eslint

Comment: yup that will do !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Update - November 3, 2017**

VS Code 1.14+ fully supports import expressions. You should no longer run into this issue

---

**Original Answer**

Import expressions are not supported in VSCode 1.13 but we just added support for them in VScode 1.14. You can try this today in the [current insiders builds](https://code.visualstudio.com/insiders)

If need to stay on 1.13, @Steffen's suggestion about setting `"javascript.validate.enable": false` is the way to go

Comment: why am i seeing it in 2020?  `const { m1: mm1, m2: mm2 } = await import(`./m.js?t=${Math.random()}`)` : Parsing error: Unexpected token import

Comment: The error is likely from one of your extensions (such as a linter)

Comment: no it's not it's because i'm using it in js fine and not ts file. if it was from a linter, it would say `eslint` there

Comment: oh yeah it probably is... i was so used to seeing "from eslint" when hovering over such errors but it's gone now, only the problems tab shows it.